# Female Guppy Health Question

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, freshwater

I went to feed my fish and I always check on my female guppies because they are the smallest in my community tank. I saw that one of my female’s gravid spot was a “odd” color to me. It is usually a dark color in that spot, but it seems like the spot got lighter. Is she possibly pregnant? Does this have to do with health of the guppy?[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, gravid spot going from dark to light over short time suggests me that she just gave birth, please look carefully for the larvae in your aquarium, they are extremely small and semi-transparent thus hard to see, other than that I cannot see any signs of health issues on this photo but I could be wrong because it's only a photo.